# Fastest way to checked checkboxes that have a value of specific list in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

This is My HTML Dom:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" name="actionChk" value="17">
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" name="actionChk" value="18">
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" name="actionChk" value="19">
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" name="actionChk" value="20">
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" name="actionChk" value="21">
```

And I have a jQuery script that returned a JSon response by ajax:

```
["18","20","21"]
```

The list can be as long as up to 200 members. So I am interested to find out the fastest way to checked checkboxes, that have a value in above list, when the response is returned. What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way would be to add an id identifier to your list of checkboxes. For example -

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" name="actionChk" value="17" id='chk-act-17' />
//incidentally, I hope the lack of a closing '/' was an oversight
//when you get your JSON response, in your ajax success or done methods
var resp = ["12", "232"],
    respLength = resp.length;
for(var i = 0; i < respLength; i += 1){
    $('#chk-act-' + resp[i]).prop('checked', true);
    //if your are using jquery 1.7+ that is, otherwise use, 
    $('#chk-act-' + resp[i]).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

### JS Perf Tests

Comparing the two current answers, the OP's requirement of "*fastest*" would be better served by going down the uglier '**id**' implementation.
**[Js Perf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-custom-perf)**

### FIddle added

[JS FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpMnJ/1/)

Posting code from fiddle-

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
    checkboxes = $('.chk');

checkboxes.each(function(i, item){
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
});

arr.forEach(function(item, i) {
    $('#chk_' + item).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: `/>` is only needed in XML (and thus XHTML) but no versions of HTML.

Comment: @powerbuoy well my mistake, XHTML it is

Comment: did not know about jsperf.com ... neat!

Answer (score 3):

Mixing jQuery on this

```
arr = ["18","20","21"];
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false); //If you need to uncheck other boxes too
$.each(arr, function(k,v) {       
   $("input[value=\""+v+"\"]").prop('checked', true);
});
```

#### [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/5ELNZ/) | [Demo 2: with all other checks removed](http://jsfiddle.net/5ELNZ/1/)

Comment: a slight correction. You need to make the rest checkboxes unchecked.

Comment: @Starx this wont work, because it will uncheck the checked checkboxes in the previous iteration. for example for 18 it will check 18, then for 20 it will uncheck 18 and check 20 only. likewise at the end this will check only for last value

Comment: @Jayanga, Oops, did a blunder there

Answer (score 2):

you can [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for checked of Checkboxes:

try this :

```
 arr = ["18","20","21"];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
 {
    if(!$("input[value="+arr[i]+"]").is(':checked'))
    { 
        $("input[value="+arr[i]+"]").attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
 }
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/tU8TP/5/

Comment: attr checked wont do...it has some problem somewhere
and again same doubt, what if we want rest of the checkboxes unchecked considering the array is coming dynamically

Comment: you can try `.attr('checked', true)` will not cause the problem

Comment: you can check fiddle that array will be changed also checkbox event occurring change.m still confuse with your requirement.

Comment: ... that's not true ... with jquery 1.6.4 (or sth around that), dom-elements with `checked="true"` where not identified with `:selected` - be aware of that!

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, but for one time use. what if I want to use it again without refreshing the html. Suppose some of the checkboxes are already checked. Then what will be the line of action?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair that was exactly my point

you can use `$(element)[0].checked=true`

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair then what is the best possible solution?

Comment: `.attr('checked', 'checked')` is the only valid one, working with all versions. `.attr('checked', true)` and `.attr('checked', false)` might always work for the ui (as the browser correctly interprets `true` as checked), but jQuery won't get it, when querying with `:checked` (in some jQuery-versions there's an explicit check against `checked`, which does not handle the value `true`)